# MongoDB aggregate: Replacing an array of IDs with the corresponding objects from an array in the same document

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in a collection:

```js
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'My document 1',
    allItems: [{
        id: 'item1',
        name: 'My item 1'
    }, {
        id: 'item2',
        name: 'My item 2'
    }, {
        id: 'item3'
        name: 'My item 3'
    }],
    containers: [{
        id: 'container1',
        selectedItems: [
            'item3',
            'item1'
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'container2',
        selectedItems: [
            'item3'
        ]
    }]
},
...]
```

I now want to write a query to find the document with a specific container ID (i.e. `container1`) and return it, while transforming it's `selectedItems` array to hold the actual object values from the `allItems` array of the same document.

I want to get this document:

```js
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'My document 1',
    container: {
        id: 'container1',
        selectedItems: [{
            id: 'item3'
            name: 'My item 3'
        }, {
            id: 'item1',
            name: 'My item 1'
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have the following aggregation (Node.js):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {'containers.id': 'container1'},
    $addFields: {
        container: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$containers', 
                as: 'container', 
                cond: {
                    $eq: ['$$container.id', 'container1']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    $project: {containers: 0},
    $unwind: {path: '$container'}

    // I now have a new property "container" with the correct subdocument from the array
    // and removed the original array with all containers.
    // I now need a stage here to populate the container subdocuments in the `selectedItems` array

    $project: {allItems: 0} // remove the list of all items when not needed anymore in a following stage
}]);
```

I know there is `$lookup`, but as I want to populate the matching array items from the same document (not a differect collection), I think I don't need it. Even when specifying the same collection in a `$lookup`, it would populate the array with the root document of my collection and it would get very complex to unwind & match the needed properties of the subdocument.

I thought about making an own `items` collection, but I would need slower lookups there and my data does not need to have these relations.

I hope my question is clear, I'm thankful for any help I can get!

I'm doing some additional transforms in my real data like copying some properties from the original root document and hiding others, but that should not matter.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `containers` array and filter by `id`
- `$arrayElemAt` to select first element from above filtered result
- `$let` to declare a variable and store do above process and store result
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `allItems` array and filter items by above result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "containers.id": "container1" } },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      container: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            container: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$containers",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.id", "container1"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            id: "$$container.id",
            selectedItems: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$allItems",
                cond: { $in: ["$$this.id", "$$container.selectedItems"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JPvHFpZp1bg)

---

The second version, you can do process stage by stage,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `containers` array and filter by `id`
- `$arrayElemAt` to select first element from above filtered result
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `allItems` array and filter items by `selectedItems`
- `$$REMOVE` will remove fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "containers.id": "container1" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      containers: "$$REMOVE",
      container: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$containers",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.id", "container1"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      allItems: "$$REMOVE",
      "container.selectedItems": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$allItems",
          cond: { $in: ["$$this.id", "$container.selectedItems"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VKXaawxrVRo)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct by not needing to use `$lookup`, a series of `$map` and `$filter` expressions is all you need.

The approach is simple, we start by filtering the required container, then we iteration over the selected container's `selectedItems` using `$map` and match the relevant fields for each item from the `allItems` field.

```
  {
    $match: {
      id: 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      container: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$containers",
                  as: "container",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$container.id",
                      "container1"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                
              },
              as: "container",
              in: {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  {
                    id: "$$container.id"
                  },
                  {
                    selectedItems: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$container.selectedItems",
                        as: "item",
                        in: {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$allItems",
                                as: "filter",
                                cond: {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$filter.id",
                                    "$$item"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SQobKD4Qery)

Comment: Thank you! The only problem for me with this solution is that my original documents can have different additional properties that I want to keep (they won't be in the transformed docs because of the exclusive `$project`). The second solution from @turivishal seems to work this way.